# An error in groupby function in pyspark code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WBpvZQ_6Gmpy6qDyJW7Xw2gXqs5iGh_8mtx4Wh1gbKE/edit?usp=sharing) on which I was asked to write a pyspark code for the following question.

```
List of Winners of Each World champions Trophy Hint: Total Result of all rounds of Tournament for that player is considered as that player's
Score/Result.
Result attributes: winner, tournament_name
```

I wrote this code:

```
game_info = spark.read.load("/content/chess/chess_wc_history_game_info.csv",
                     format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")

game_info.groupBy('winner').show()
```

But on execution I got an error as:

```
AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Comment: the error is quite explanatory. there is no `show()` method on `df.groupBy()`. the `agg()` has to accompany it.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? what are you trying to compute ?

Comment: `List of Winners of Each World champions Trophy Hint: Total Result of all rounds of Tournament for that player is considered as that player's
Score/Result.
Result attributes: winner, tournament_name` this is what I have to find out

Answer (score 4):

This error is there because `groupBy()` contains only below mentioned functions:

- `count()` - Returns the count of rows for each group.
- `mean()` - Returns the mean of values for each group.
- `max()` - Returns the maximum of values for each group.
- `min()` - Returns the minimum of values for each group.
- `sum()` - Returns the total for values for each group.
- `avg()` - Returns the average for values for each group.
- `agg()` - Using `agg()` function, we can calculate more than one aggregation at a time.
- `pivot()` - This function is used to Pivot the DataFrame.

Comment: so for this question do i need to apply max() function?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another usefull function to @numb's list

`collect_list` - Collects all the values for a specific column foreach group

I guess this would help to "see" the groups

side note: truncate=False in `show` method print the table without truncating long text so you can actually see all the values

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list

game_info.groupBy('winner').agg(collect_list("<column you want to fetch>").alias('group_values')).show(truncate=False)
```